# How can a function defined on symmetrically placed interval be written as sum of an even and odd function?

Tags: fourier-series, even-and-odd-functions

I know how to find Fourier series of a function,but i found following question and I stuck.

> "Show that any function $f(x)$ defined on symmetrically placed intervals can be written as sum of an even function and an odd function .
>
> Hence show that how to write $f(x) =x+x^2+x^3$ as per above statement.

Can anyone please help me...thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not use Fourier series.  Given any $f(x)$, find $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$ so that $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$. For example $g(x) = e^{f(x)} + e^{f(-x)}$ is even, but of course you can make a much simpler function $g$ that is even.

Comment: Can you tell which terms of your $f(x)$ are even and which are odd? Group them accordingly.

Comment: @MPW x and x^3 are odd and x^2 is even

Comment: So doesn't that mean that $f(x)=\underbrace{(x^2)}_{\textrm{even}} + \underbrace{(x+x^3)}_{\textrm{odd}}$ fits the bill?

Comment: @MPW now i got it...f(x)=h(x)+g(x),.   Where h(x)=x^2 is even  and g(x)=x+x^3 is odd....thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(x)=h(x)+g(x)$ where $h(x)$ is even, $g(x)$ is odd. Then $f(-x)=h(x)-g(x)$. Adding both equations we get that $h(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$ and $g(x)=...$

Comment: g(x)=f(x) - f(-x)/2...thank you sir